# Best way to handle serverside validations using jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

```
$('form[id^=comment_add]').live("submit",function()
{
    var id= this.id.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');      
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $("#comment_add"+id).serialize(), function(data)
    {
        /*do something*/
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        displayError(errorThrown, id);
    });
    reloaded();
    return false;
});
```

Currently i am throwing a HTTP error with the response containing the json string. and then parsing the json string and showing the errors. Is this a good way or are there better ways. or which is the recommended way to display server side validation

Comment: what server side are you using, php? .net ? etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is good idea. Even StackOverflow throws different error codes when error appears. Use this one you're using